# Error JS -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

been trying to find out the cause of this issue but no avail, was hoping someone could chime in.

Here's the JS, the error occurs on line 17. I have also attached the html under this if it helps any. Thanks.

```js
function edit_row(id)
{
 var order=document.getElementById("order_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var link=document.getElementById("link_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var date=document.getElementById("date_val"+id).innerHTML;

 document.getElementById("order_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='order_text"+id+"' value='"+order+"'>";
 document.getElementById("link_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='link_text"+id+"' value='"+link+"'>";
 document.getElementById("date_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='date_text"+id+"' value='"+date+"'>";
 
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";
}

function save_row(id)
{
 var order=document.getElementById("order_text"+id).value;
 var link=document.getElementById("link_text"+id).value;
 var date=document.getElementById("date_text"+id).value;
 
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   edit_row:'edit_row',
   row_id:id,
   order_val:order,
   link_val:link,
   date_val:date
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    document.getElementById("order_val"+id).innerHTML=order;
    document.getElementById("link_val"+id).innerHTML=link;
    document.getElementById("date_val"+id).innerHTML=date;
    document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="none";
   }
  }
 });
}

function delete_row(id)
{
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   delete_row:'delete_row',
   row_id:id,
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
   }
  }
 });
}

function insert_row()
{
 var order=document.getElementById("new_order").value;
 var link=document.getElementById("new_link").value;
 var date=document.getElementById("new_date").value;

 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
   insert_row:'insert_row',
   order_val:order,
   link_val:link,
   date_val:date
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response!="")
   {
    var id=response;
    var table=document.getElementById("user_table");
    var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
    var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+id+"'><td id='order_val"+id+"'>"+order+"</td><td id='link_val"+id+"'>"+link+"</td><td id='date_val"+id+"'>"+date+"</td><td><input type='button' class='edit_button' id='edit_button"+id+"' value='edit' onclick='edit_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='save_button' id='save_button"+id+"' value='save' onclick='save_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='delete_button' id='delete_button"+id+"' value='delete' onclick='delete_row("+id+");'/></td></tr>";

    document.getElementById("new_order").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_link").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_date").value="";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="7.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

        <?php
        $host="localhost";
        $username="empty";
        $password="empty";
        $databasename="empty";
        $connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
        $db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

        $select =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_detail");
        ?>

        <table align="center" cellpadding="10" border="1" id="user_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Total order(s)</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
            ?>
                <tr id="row<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                    <td id="order_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['order'];?></td>
                    <td id="link_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['link'];?></td>
                    <td id="date_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                        <input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="save" onclick="save_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                        <input type='button' class="delete_button" id="delete_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="delete" onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
                <tr id="new_row">
                    <td><input type="text" id="new_order"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="new_link"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="new_date"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row();"></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

modify_records.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$userlink="empty";
$password="empty";
$databaselink="empty";

$connect=mysql_connect($host,$userlink,$password);
$db=mysql_select_db($databaselink);

if(isset($_POST['edit_row']))
{
 $row=$_POST['row_id'];
 $order=$_POST['order_val'];
 $link=$_POST['link_val'];
 $date=$_POST['date_val'];

 mysql_query("update user_detail set order='$order',link='$link',date='$date' where id='$row'");
 echo "success";
 exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['delete_row']))
{
 $row_no=$_POST['row_id'];
 mysql_query("delete from user_detail where id='$row_no'");
 echo "success";
 exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['insert_row']))
{
 $order=$_POST['order_val'];
 $link=$_POST['link_val'];
 $date=$_POST['date_val'];
 mysql_query("insert into user_detail values('','$order','$link','$date')");
 echo mysql_insert_id();
 exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: does an element with the ID 'link_text"+id exist?

Comment: This error occur when we try to access property of null element. So make sure every element exists in javascript function

Comment: is the input box properly appended with the dynamic id inside td? can you check that using F12 dev tools?

Comment: I am not sure, I have updated the line 35 on the JS but still not working and also attached the modify_records.php if it helps anyone with this.                     `document.getElementById("order_val"+id).innerHTML=link;
  document.getElementById("link_val"+id).innerHTML=link;`

Comment: honestly, this is some of the scariest code I've seen in quite some time. 
you are mixing database access logic with your html layer; you are reading in from $_POST without filtering or validating; you are using those $_POST parameters in your SQL; you are not escaping the output that you're displaying; and, if I'm not mistaken, the very database API you are using is deprecated.

On the client side you are using jQuery for ajax, so you might as well take advantage of it for your DOM manipulation as well.

My advice? Dump all of this and start over. Just sayin'.

Comment: My friend you need to start using Frameworks, your code is a nightmare. Do a favor to your future self and organize it, trust me, you will thank later. Just a constructive advice, not trying to offend, cheers.

Comment: Trying to answer, you need to check  first if return from getElementById returned some object, it is because of it you are having problems.